# Generate 50 random numbers and store them into an array c++

Tags: visual-c++

this is what i have of the function so far. This is only the beginning of the problem, it is asking to generate the random numbers in a 10 by 5 group of numbers for the output, then after this it is to be sorted by number size, but i am just trying to get this first part down.

```
/* Populate the array with 50 randomly generated integer values
* in the range 1-50. */
void populateArray(int ar[], const int n) {
    int n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length - 1; i++){

        for (int i = 1; i <= ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            i = rand() % 10 + 1;
            ar[n]++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please compile with maximum warning level. If you do so, your compiler should warn you that you are declaring a local variable n when another variable n already exists (you are thus hiding the parameter n). And you are using this uninitialized n in your line "ar[n]++". Also: what is length? What is ARRAY_SIZE? What is n supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

First of all we want to use `std::array`; It has some nice property, one of which is that it doesn't decay as a pointer. Another is that it knows its size. In this case we are going to use templates to make `populateArray` a generic enough algorithm.

```
template<std::size_t N>
void populateArray(std::array<int, N>& array) { ... }
```

Then, we would like to remove all "raw" `for` loops. [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) in combination with some random generator seems a good option.

For the number generator we can use [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Specifically [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). For that we need to get some generator up and running:

```
std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generator(device());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, N);
```

and use it in our [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) algorithm:

```
std::generate_n(array.begin(), N, [&dist, &generator](){ 
    return dist(generator); 
});
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77f2ec1ab3fed7f5)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but the only problem with this is i was given main and all the functions already, we have to build the functions accordingly